# How to add blend mode to PDF elements via Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I make use of the [PDContentStreamEditor.class](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/PdfContentStreamEditor.java) to convert the Colorspace from PDF page elements. I saw that there is the  PDExtendedGraphicsState.class where a BlendMode can be set.

```
PDExtendedGraphicsState extendedGraphicsState = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
extendedGraphicsState.setBlendMode(BlendMode.MULTIPLY);
```

I could not find out where to set the extendedGraphicsState. I hope someone can help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

I have to add the extendedGraphicsState to the page resources and then use it for the gs operators.

```
final PDExtendedGraphicsState gState = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
        gState.setBlendMode(BlendMode.MULTIPLY);

COSName gStateInternalName = page.getResources().add(gState);

 PdfContentStreamEditor identity = new PdfContentStreamEditor(document, page) {
                @Override
                protected void write(ContentStreamWriter contentStreamWriter,
                        Operator operator,
                        List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException {


                    if (operator.getName().equals("gs")) {
                        operands.clear();
                        operands.add(gStateInternalName);
                    }
super.write(contentStreamWriter, operator, operands);
}
```

Comment: If that works for you, great! If I see this correctly, though, you *replace* every existing **gs** operation by one that sets your desired blend mode. Thus, the graphics state changes done by the original **gs** operations are lost. If you don't want that, simply additionally call `super.write(...)` for the original operation before changing the operands. Also this requires that the original content stream uses **gs** operations at all. If you also want to support documents that don't use **gs** operations, simply send one additional **gs** operation for your `gState` when starting the page.